# Signup to StackExchange using previous existing login

Tags: support, user-accounts

I already have a TeX.SE login and password which I would like to use to login to this site and would prefer not to use other logins that I may have from other sites like Google or Facebook. 
How can I do that?

Comment: This should already be possible. What is preventing you to do so?

Comment: Go to http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/login and click “log in wtih Stack Exchange”.